# How to access Heroku environment variables with Nuxt.JS app

Tags: heroku, configuration, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I have deployed my app on Heroku and on the start of my app I check a config file and in there I want to access a config var I have created on Heroku `API_KEY` to define my Firebase config:

```
module.exports = {
  fireConfig: {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-project-id",
    storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "my-messaging-sender-id"
    }
};
```

this `process.env.API_KEY` is `undefined`. Should I use a different way to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [define environment variables in your `nuxt.config.js` file](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/), e.g.

```
export default {
  env: {
    firebaseApiKey: process.env.API_KEY || 'default value'
  }
}
```

Here we use the `API_KEY` environment variable, if it's available, and assign that to `firebaseApiKey`.

If that environment variable isn't set, e.g. maybe in development (you can set it there too if you want), we fall back to `'default value'`. Please *don't* put your real API key in `'default value'`. You could use a separate throwaway Firebase account key here or just omit it (take `|| 'default value'` right out) and rely on the environment variable being set.

These will be [processed at build time](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/#process-env-) and then made available using the name you give them, e.g.

```
module.exports = {
  fireConfig: {
    apiKey: process.env.firebaseApiKey,  # Not API_KEY
    // ...
};
```