# How can I hidden my aws key and secret using Nuxt JS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

Is there a way to keep my aws secret and keyId, using NuxtJ? I use them to upload files to my buckets, and for sure, I would like to keep my credentials hidden.
Thanks

Following the code that I am using to upload files to Amazon S3

```
async PutAmazonBucket() {
      if (this.selectedFile) { 


        AWS.config.update({
           accessKeyId: "",
         secretAccessKey: "",
         region: ""
       });
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = {
          Bucket: "buvketName",
          Key:
            "folder/" +
            Date.now() +
            "_" +
            this.selectedFile.name,
          ContentType: this.selectedFile.type,
          Body: this.selectedFile,
          ACL: "public-read"
        };

        await s3
          .putObject(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              alert("Error, please try again.");
              this.showProgess = false;
            } else {
              this.editedItem.fileUrl =
                "https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/" +
                params.Bucket +
                "/" +
                params.Key;
              this.uploadComplete();
              alert("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
          })
          .on("httpUploadProgress", (progressEvent) => {
            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            );
          });
      }
    },
```

Comment: This is something you should do with the AWS CLI. Here are the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html).

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to [keep a `.aws/credentials` file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) in your home directory. The AWS CLI, as well as many packages that use it, will look there by default.

So you will have a file, `~/.aws/credentials` (no extension), with this info:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

You can keep other less sensitive configuration options in `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json
```

Edit: The above solution isn't specific to Nuxt. I'm making assumptions but if you're working off of [this Gulp example from the Nuxt docs for deploying to s3](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/deployment-aws-s3-cloudfront/) you can just delete the `credentials` block altogether if you have them stored in `~/.aws/`.

---

Edit 2: To clarify, if using the default profile (above), the AWS CLI will look there for your credentials by default. You do not need to reference them at all in your script. But if for some reason it complains you could [set it explicitly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html) in your deploy script with:

```js
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
```

That method is typically used to specify a profile other than the default, since you shouldn't need to specify the default. For example if you have a personal AWS account and a work AWS account, you could keep your work credentials in the same `~/.aws/credentials` files with another entry for `[work]` and replace `{profile: 'default'}` with `{profile: 'work'}` in your deploy script.

---

Edit 3: The above assumes you are deploying to s3 from your local machine. If a server will be uploading the files instead, you can set your credentials as environment variables. [For heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#credentials):

```sh
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy AWS_REGION=zzz
```

And then access them in your upload script as you were:

```js
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: proccess.env.AWS_REGION
});
```

[Managing config vars in Heroku:](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars)

> Whenever you set or remove a config var using any method, your app is restarted and a new release is created.
>
> Config var values are persistent–they remain in place across deploys and app restarts. Unless you need to change a value, you only need to set it once.

Comment: Thanks, How can I access the credentials after that?

Comment: The CLI will look there by default, you don't need to reference credentials at all in your script. Adding to answer with an example of setting it explicitly.

Comment: Answer updated. Does that help? If not, please elaborate on how you are currently uploading to s3 and maybe I can clarify.

Comment: Nope, it is not working, I am receiving the following error: "AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials is not a constructor"

Comment: @ZeusAC could you post your upload script? Hard to tell where it's going wrong without the code

Comment: @ZeusAC You are overriding the default and setting the credentials to empty strings - delete this part and it should work if you put the credentials file in right place: `AWS.config.update({
           accessKeyId: "",
         secretAccessKey: "",
         region: ""
       });`.

Comment: No, I let empty to no show my data. Do I need to delete " AWS.config.update" ?  Sorry, in a Nuxt project where should I put the credentials files? Thank you

Comment: Yes, delete `AWS.config.update({...})`. You do not need to keep or reference your credentials files anywhere inside your Nuxt project. The AWS CLI will automatically look for them in `~/.aws/config`, with `~/` being your home directory (On Mac this would be `Users/ZeusAC/`).

Comment: ok, so when I promote to production, the nuxt it is gonna find my credentials? I am using Heroku to publish my site

Comment: @ZeusAC I don't understand. Are you not publishing to s3? This will not work for Heroku.

Comment: Sorry, for lack of explanation. I only have a feature to upload files to S3 Bucket. However, my application is a Universal that I am publishing in Heroku. My main concern is to let the secret, and key in my front end application

Comment: Oooh ok. That would have been good to know ;) Updated my answer to show Heroku config

Comment: It works, however, I needed to declare into the nuxt.config and as result, my secret and key are displayed in production.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by declare into the nuxt.config

Comment: To work properly, I need to declare process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, inside of nuxt.confing, otherwise,  I will receive undefined field by Heroku.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#credentials)? `$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy AWS_REGION=zzz`
Once you set those in Heroku you should not need to also set them in your nuxt.config

Comment: I have done, but it does not work yet. I received the following error ""Missing credentials in config". Only when I insert in the nuxt.config works, however, everyone can see my password.

Comment: Are you getting that error on the server or when you test locally? And do you get the error when you try to set the config in Heroku or from your Nuxt app? I'm assuming you did replace the `xxx`, `yyy`, `zzz` with your actual credentials right? What do you get when you log `process.env` at runtime after you set your credentials in `heroku config`?

Comment: I am getting the error on the server. The error occurs when I try to upload a file. It is like Nuxt js does not recognize vars from Heroku. I followed all the instructions. This guy has almost the same problem "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704031/how-to-access-heroku-environment-variables-with-nuxt-js-app"

Comment: Did you try logging `process.env` at runtime? If so, can you post the log?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it shows undefined. It reads process.env.NODE_ENV, however, process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is coming undefined

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use nuxt [server middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-api-endpoint)
server middleware runs on server side, so your secret can not be found from the browser